# Finding C and L in an L-type impedance matching network

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

[image]
I'm struggling with finding the values of C and L in the circuit above. I understand the point of the L and C, is to match the real parts of the impedances and eliminate the imaginary parts, but I have a hard time calculating this.

From the equation above, I'm supposed to be able to create 2 equations, one for real parts and one for the imaginary parts. I just don't know how to do that yet.

Edit:
Here are the values of the components:
[image]
I'm assuming Z1 can be written as R1+jX1 and Z2 as R2+jX2.
Then the first equation can be written like this:
[image]
where ct is *. Also X2 is left out, because Y2=1/Z2 is purely real.
So now I would have to separate the real and imaginary parts:
[image]

But the two last equations don't really look right, but I donät know what I'm doing wrong either.

Edit 2:
From the two equations I got C=-3.17nF and L=-112.5nH. I'm surprised the units are correct, but they definitely shouldn't be negative though.

Comment: If you have a "real" case, just use https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/interactive-design-tools/rf-impedance-matching-calculator.html

Comment: Yeah, but I want to solve this with equations like I commented below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not entirely certain about your specific objective at the moment. However, if I understand correctly, you wish to address the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\Re\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{g}}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)&=\Re\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}}\space\text{||}\space\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)\\
\\
\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{g}}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)&=\Im\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}}\space\text{||}\space\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\right)
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

Rewriting this, gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\Re\left(\hat{\text{Z}}_\text{g}\exp\left(\theta_\text{g}\text{j}\right)+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)&=\Re\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}^2+\left(\omega\text{C}\right)^2}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}^2+\left(\omega\text{C}\right)^2}\right)\\
\\
\Im\left(\hat{\text{Z}}_\text{g}\exp\left(\theta_\text{g}\text{j}\right)+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)&=\Im\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}^2+\left(\omega\text{C}\right)^2}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}^2+\left(\omega\text{C}\right)^2}\right)
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

So, we get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\hat{\text{Z}}_\text{g}\cos\left(\theta_\text{g}\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}^2+\left(\omega\text{C}\right)^2}\\
\\
\hat{\text{Z}}_\text{g}\sin\left(\theta_\text{g}\right)+\omega\text{L}&=-\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}^2+\left(\omega\text{C}\right)^2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Which gives:

$$\text{L}=-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\left(\hat{\text{Z}}_\text{g}\sin\left(\theta_\text{g}\right)+\frac{\displaystyle\omega\text{C}}{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}^2+\left(\omega\text{C}\right)^2}\right)\tag4$$
$$\text{C}=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\omega}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle\text{Y}_\text{L}}{\displaystyle\hat{\text{Z}}_\text{g}\cos\left(\theta_\text{g}\right)}-\text{Y}_\text{L}^2}\tag5$$

Which is not possible because \$\displaystyle\text{L}>0\$ and \$(4)\$ leads to \$\displaystyle\text{L}<0\$.